# How do I create a list of functions that have an unspecified return type?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need a list of functions but I don't want to specify the return type because they will have different return types.

```
typedef ReturnType(*TokenFunc) (std::string left, std::string right);
std::vector<TokenFunc> tokenFuncs;
```

I want `ReturnType` to be unspecified.

Is there a way to do this or is it impossible?

Comment: The usual suspects... a tuple if the list is known at compile-time, or a vector of variants where the variant members are the possible function types

Comment: Do the return types derive from a common base?

Comment: No as one may be a Boolean and one may be a void.

Comment: You can use `std::function<void(std::string,std::string)>` to unify the function types.

Comment: @RemyLebeau — no, it doesn’t require a `void` return type. It defines a function object whose **function call operator** returns `void`. Internally it will discard any value that the target function returns.

Comment: std::any - try this might help you. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any